# Compare array with data in database

Tags: php, arrays

I'm making an API call to get my friends and the array I get for this I need to "filter" the array with which ID that is found in the database. Now the results is just "null".

This is the array (defined as variable $friends):

```
 [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "One friends name"
    ["id"]=>
    string(8) "FRIEND_ID"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Another friends name"
    ["id"]=>
    string(9) "ANOTHER_FRIEND_ID"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "Another friends name"
    ["id"]=>
    string(9) "ANOTHER_FRIEND_ID"
  }
```

And the PHP code, where I want to "filter the array with the ID's in the database:

```
$query_top_list_friends = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$DBprefix."users 
          WHERE center_id='" . $personal['center_id'] . "' ORDER BY 
          workouts DESC LIMIT 10");
$i=0;                            

$friends = $friends['data'];

foreach($friends as $friend) 
{                        
    while ($top_list_friends = mysql_fetch_array($query_top_list_friends))
    {                    
       if($friend['id']==$top_list_friends['fid']) 
       {
         $i++;
         echo "<div class='user'>";
         echo "<span class='number'>" . $i . "</span>";
         echo "<span class='name'>" . $top_list_friends['name'] . "</span>";
         echo "<span class='workouts'>" . $top_list_friends['workouts'] . "</span>";
         echo "</div>";
       } 
    }  
}
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I'm made some changes to this, but still no results:

```
                $friends = array($friends['data']);

                while ($top_list_friends = mysql_fetch_array($query_top_list_friends)) {                    

                                if($friend[$top_list_friends['fid']]) {

                                $i++;
                                    echo "<div class='user'>";
                                    echo "<span class='number'>" . $i . "</span>";
                                    echo "<span class='name'>" . $top_list_friends['name'] . "</span>";
                                    echo "<span class='workouts'>" . $top_list_friends['workouts'] . "</span>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                } 
                }
```

Comment: First use print_r(top_list_friends ) and print_r($friends['data']) for debugging and paste it with the post if possible

Answer (score 0):

Try to change $friends array like this:

```
$friends = array ("FRIEND_ID"=>"One friends name", "ANOTHER_FRIEND_ID"=>"Another friends name");
```

AND THEN:

```
while ($top_list_friends = mysql_fetch_array($query_top_list_friends)) {                    

                if($friend[$top_list_friends['fid']]) {

                $i++;
                    echo "<div class='user'>";
                    echo "<span class='number'>" . $i . "</span>";
                    echo "<span class='name'>" . $top_list_friends['name'] . "</span>";
                    echo "<span class='workouts'>" . $top_list_friends['workouts'] . "</span>";
                    echo "</div>";
                } 
}
```

WITHOUT foreach($friends as $friend) LOOP :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still don't get any results. I made an update in my question, based on your answer, but maybe I'm doing something wrong?